# MongoDB addFields to an array within the document

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I have a document as added below

```
{
  "bookingReference": "225360",
  "portOfDestination": "TRKSP",
  "contactPerson": "FAHRI YUMUSAK TRANS.",
  "cargoDetails": [
    {
      "quantity": "123",
      "unitType": "123",
      "cargoDescription": "123",
      "cargoGrossWeight": 123
    }
  ],
  "passengerDetails": [
    {
      "quantity": "123",
      "unitType": "123",
      "passengerDescription": "123"
    },
    {
      "quantity": "1234",
      "unitType": "1234",
      "passengerDescription": "1234"
    }
  ]
}
```

The problem is that I want to add the **contactPerson** to every object within the array passengerDetails.
So after addition the array **passengerDetails** should look like

```
"passengerDetails": [
    {
      "quantity": "123",
      "unitType": "123",
      "passengerDescription": "123",
      "contactPerson": "FAHRI YUMUSAK TRANS."
    },
    {
      "quantity": "1234",
      "unitType": "1234",
      "passengerDescription": "1234",
      "contactPerson": "FAHRI YUMUSAK TRANS."   
    }
  ]
```

I'm able to achieve this by $addFields the problem arises when the passengerDetails array is empty/null/notExists. I want that the a single object of passengerDetails should be created and added to passengerDeails. The end result should be.

```
"passengerDetails": [
    {
      "contactPerson": "FAHRI YUMUSAK TRANS."
    }
  ]
```

If I use $addFields then for the later case the mongo generates something like

```
"passengerDetails": 
    {
      "contactPerson": "FAHRI YUMUSAK TRANS."
    }
```

please help to resolve this

I tried using addFields but all of my use-case wern't served.

Answer (score 0):

Your `passengerDetails` is an array field. You can use `$map` to iterate through the items and use `$mergeObjects` to set the field for `contactPerson`

```js
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $set: {
      passengerDetails: {
        $map: {
          input: "$passengerDetails",
          as: "pd",
          in: {
            $mergeObjects: [
              "$$pd",
              {
                "contactPerson": "$contactPerson"
              }
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "$set": {
      "passengerDetails": {
        "$cond": {
          "if": {
            $eq: [
              {
                $ifNull: [
                  "$passengerDetails",
                  []
                ]
              },
              []
            ]
          },
          "then": [
            {
              "contactPerson": "$contactPerson"
            }
          ],
          "else": "$passengerDetails"
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "$merge": {
      "into": "collection",
      "on": "_id"
    }
  }
])
```

[Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/DHtH_NDMUVw)

Comment: Hi @ray can you help me with the aggregate query!

Comment: This isn't working when the array passengerDetails is empty. The contact person isn't getting added.

Comment: @Jatin updated the answer. Just add another conditional checking for empty cases right before the `$merge`